# Processing Large file from remote dynamic source using spring-boot-starter-integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have a use case to read large files from dynamic sources, a source could be either an S3 bucket or a remote file path. The size of the files does not permit me to move them over to the local disk before processing. I would prefer to stream data from those files and process them on the fly.

```
ReadRecord -> TransformRecord -> 
RouteRecordByType -> AggregateRecordBasedOnTypeAndCountOf1000 ->
StoreRecordOnALocalFileBackedChannel -> WriteRecordsInGroupsOf1000 -> S3Bucket.
```

I have used spring integration several and I am pretty comfortable with its construct and patterns. I am thinking of using `FileReadingMessageSources` to get my datasource on the fly but have not seen any example of file system backed Channels. Most examples in documentations use databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a streaming solution from the remote source, you need to take a look into the `S3StreamingMessageSource`, `FtpStreamingMessageSource` and `SftpStreamingMessageSource`, if that a case for you. This type of `MessageSource` just opens an `InputStream` for the remote file and allows you to do whatever you need locally in the memory.

I'm not sure what you mean about *file system backed Channels*, but maybe with a streaming message source solution you won't need to think about that anymore.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Artem for the prompt response. The reason I am talking about filesystem-backed-channel is because I need to make sure the whole file is processed successfully before proceeding to the next step. That is, writing the entire processed data back to s3 bucket in a set of 1000. So if the file or s3 bucket source contains 1,000,000 records, I will end up with 1000 payload aggregated by some defined values. I need to keep these sets of aggregates in the file system until the entire file is processed then push them over to S3.

Comment: OK. So, how about to have some persistent message store in between? What is wrong with data base so far? There is just no plain file system store, since any DB is handling their data into file system anyway, but we much more  robustness, than we would do ourselves with plain file system.

Comment: This makes a whole lot of sense, thanks again. Would you agree that there will be some additional cost involved writing to a database on a managed infrastructure. I guess the challenge here now is to look at that cost and see how that would affect the bottom line. Otherwise, look at the DB backed channel and see if I can implement a custom file system backed channel.

Comment: Another option would be to use an H2 in filesystem mode to back the channel and then delete all records after processing. Any opinion about this approach?